# Does |z|= Cos(θ)+isin(θ)

Tags: complex-analysis

If $|z| = \cos{(θ)}+i\sin{(θ)}$. If so then does $\cos{(2θ)}+i\sin{(2θ)}$ correlate to any modulus of $z$? I have a faction in the form of $$\frac{\cos{(2θ)}+i\sin{(2θ)}+3(\cos{(θ)}+i\sin{(θ)})+2}{\cos{(2θ)}+isin{(2θ)}+2(\cos{(θ)}+i\sin{(θ)})+1}$$ and I'm trying to reduce it in the form of the $|z|$.

Comment: If $z = x + yi$, where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, then $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ since $|z|$ is the distance of the point $(x, y)$ from the origin of the complex plane.

Comment: If $|z|=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta,$ then $\theta=2\pi k$ for some integer $k.$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The modulus (or magnitude) a complex number $z=x+iy$, is defined as $$|z|:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\in\mathbb{R}$$

Writing $z$ in polar form, $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ by means of the transformations $$\begin{align} x&\to r\cos\theta \\ y &\to r\sin\theta\end{align}$$ and substituting these values into the definition of the modulus yields $$\begin{align}|z|&=\sqrt{r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)} \\ &= \sqrt{r^2(1)}\end{align}$$

In other words, no, the modulus of $|z|$ has no dependence on $\theta$, the argument of the complex number. It is simply a real number which is greater or equal to 0. This result shows that the expression on the RHS in the question must also be real. Hence $i\sin\theta=0$.

I hope this clarifies things for you. Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean by the RHS implies $i\sin{\theta}=0$? This statement is false, as $2i\sin{\theta}=e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}$.

Comment: Saying $i\sin{(\theta)} = 0$ means that $|z| = \cos{(\theta)}$. That contradicts your statement that $|z|$ doesn't depend on $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute vaule of $z$ is $|z|= |\cos\theta + i \sin \theta|=1$. This doesn’t help you for the given task.

Hint:

$$z=\cos\theta + i \sin \theta $$
$$z^2= \cos2\theta + i \sin 2\theta $$

Use the expression and try to factor the numerator and denominator.